# Comma separated values to variable in JSON Extractor

Tags: jmeter

[image]

I am getting comma separated values to the variable pUsername in JSON Extractor. My values also have comma and which is creating problem while using the split function to store these values to an array of string.How can I store the values to variable pUsername instead of with comma separator (for example with "-" ).
With comma separator the variable pUsername  have the values like Test,user1,Test,user2,Test,user3,Test,user4. I want the variable pUsername have the values like Test,user1-Test,user2-Test,user3-Test,user4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the JSON Extractor
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('pUsername', vars.get('pUsername').replaceAll('(\\w+),(\\w+),', '$1,$2-'))
   ```
3. That's it, the commas in usernames will be replaced by dashes according to the pattern you specified

In the above code snippet `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on JMeter API shortcuts available for the JSR223 Test Elements.